# How to integrate browserstack with Nativescript using Appium?

Tags: nativescript, appium

I have tried it a lot but not able to figure out why my tests are not running on Browser Stack.

1 - Package that i have installed
     nativescript-dev-appium

Steps that i have done successfully are as follows:
1 - APK uploaded to Browser Stack.
2 - Used command to run test: npm run e2e android.

Below are the processes which happens successfully on browser stack but at last point it always timeout.

Initializing Device
00:14
1
Downloading App
00:14
6
Installing App
00:14
3
Setting Up Appium
00:14
1
Setting Up Network Connection
00:21
7
Launching App
01:53
0
STOP SESSION
IDLE TIMEOUT

Code is as follows:-

```
var wd = require('wd');
var assert = require('assert');
var asserters = wd.asserters;
var capabilities = {
 'device' : 'Samsung Galaxy S8',
 'os_version' : '7.0'
}

Object.assign(capabilities, {
  'browserstack.user' : 'nitintayal1',
  'browserstack.key' : 'WhpbGSn97yyy2HSY3XtN',
  'project': 'My First Project',
  'build' : 'My First Build',
  'name': 'Bstack-[Node] Sample Test',
  "app" : "bs://ee1e2103d4826968e28630ccee562059ec10fadd",
  "automationName":"UIAutomator2"
});

let driver = wd.promiseRemote("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub");

driver
  .init(capabilities)
  //Write your code here
  .then(function(){
      assert(true);
  })
  .fin(function() { return driver.quit(); })
  .done();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem you are integrating nativescript-dev-appium package anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Manoj - Could you please reply me on this? How we can integrate nativescript-dev-appium package here?